# Верстка блока меню и поиска

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Помогите сверстать блок меню. не могу разобраться как сделать все в один ряд

Вот СSS-код и HTML-код

```css
/*меню*/
.menu {
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 max-width: 760px;
 float: left;
}

.menu a {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #717171;
 display: block; /* меняем отображение на блок, чтобы иметь возможность задавать внутренние отступы */
    padding: 10px 13px;
 background-color: #DDDDDD;

}

.menu .active {
 color: #fff;
 background-color: #D45757;
}

.menu ul {
 /*
 font-size: 0;
 */
}

.menu li {
 display: inline-block;
 font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 height: 40px;
}

/*конец меню*/

/*поиск*/

#search-block-form {
 margin-top: 20px;
 margin-left: 0px;
 text-align: center;
 /*
 max-width: 760px;
 */
 float: left;
}

#search-block-form{
 width:250px;
 height:28px;
 border:#c9c9c9 solid 1px;
 background:url(images/searchBg.png) left top repeat-x;
 box-shadow:0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
 }
.focus-active{
 border-color:#aaa !important;
 background:#fff !important;
 }
#search-block-form input{
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
 display:block;
 border:none;
 outline:none;
 background:none;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
 }
#search-block-form .form-actions{
 width:58px;
 height:28px;
 float:right;
 border:#a8b5b9 solid 1px;
 margin:-1px -1px 0 0;
 background:url(images/submit.png) left top repeat; 
 }
#search-block-form .form-actions input:hover{
 cursor:pointer;
 }
#search-block-form .form-actions input{
 overflow:hidden;
 font:11px/16px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#a8b5b9;
 }
#search-block-form .form-item{
 width:157px;
 padding:0 0 0 33px;
 float:left;
 height:28px;
 background:url(images/searchIcon.png) 3px 2px no-repeat;
 }
#search-block-form .form-item input{
 font:13px/16px "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#222;
 height:auto !important;
 padding:6px 0;
 }
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Music</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Movies</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">TV Series</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fashion</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Health</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Photography</a></li>
   </ul>
   <form action="" method="post" id="search-block-form">
         <div class="form-item">
           <input type="text" name="" value="" maxlength="128" placeholder="SEARCH AWESOMAG">
         </div>
         <div class="form-actions">
           <input type="submit" name="op" value="" class="form-submit">
       </div>
   </form>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
/*меню*/

.menu {
  margin-top: 20px;
  max-width: 760px;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 12px;
}
.menu a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #717171;
  display: block;
  padding: 0 5px;
  line-height: 30px;
  background-color: #DDDDDD;
}
.menu .active {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #D45757;
}
.menu ul {
  flex: 4 0;
}
.menu li {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans, sans-serif;
  font-size: 11px;
}
/*конец меню*/

/*поиск*/

#search-block-form {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0;
  height: 28px;
  border: #a8b5b9 solid 1px;
  background: url(images/searchBg.png) left top repeat-x;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
.focus-active {
  border-color: #aaa !important;
  background: #fff !important;
}
#search-block-form input {
  display: block;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
}
#search-block-form .form-item {
  flex: 1 0;
  height: 28px;
  background: url(images/submit.png) left top repeat;
}
#search-block-form .form-actions input:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
#search-block-form .form-actions input {
  overflow: hidden;
  font: 11px/16px"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #a8b5b9;
}
#search-block-form .form-actions {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  flex: 0 0 28px;
  border-left: #a8b5b9 solid 1px;
  background: url(images/searchIcon.png) 3px 2px no-repeat;
}
#search-block-form .form-item input {
  font: 10px/28px"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: #222;
  padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<nav class="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#" class="active">Music</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Movies</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">TV Series</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Education</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Fashion</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Health</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Photography</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form action="" method="post" id="search-block-form">
    <div class="form-item">
      <input type="text" name="" value="" maxlength="128" placeholder="SEARCH AWESOMAG">
    </div>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <input type="submit" name="op" value="" class="form-submit">
    </div>
  </form>
</nav>
```